# How can a for-loop that touches no important code change program output?

Tags: python, for-loop, output

I'm working on a relatively large python file, and am working on adding in the next important feature. However, I've noticed that inserting ANY `for` loop is changing the program's output.

To test this, I put in the following loop:

```
for fff in range(2):
    print 'test'
```

The variable `fff` appears nowhere else in the code. Output is iterated through a list called `trueRepeats`, which clearly is not touched by this code (nor is any variable, for that matter). And yet, no matter where in the code I put this loop -- even before `trueRepeats` is declared; even if it's the first code that is executed after the imports, the output changes.

**EDIT:** Here is the full source: [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/teamawesome/pyredund/src/e97bfa2e8595c73164076c6a4a9d18b8e98e49f4/tree_repeat.py?at=master). The original location where I tried to add the loop was under comment block #4, but as mentioned, it seemed to cause an issue in a variety of other places. I'm running on the file "example.py" also in the repository. Without the loop, the program returns two repeats, at lines {4, 7} and {1, 10}. With the loop, it returns instances at {2, 3} and {1, 10}.

I know this is not much code to go off of, but before I can diagnose what the issue is, I don't even have a *clue* how this is possible, which is my question: What in python would make it so that an independent for-loop can be affecting output that only involves variables that the loop doesn't touch?

**EDIT 2:** When I talk about the output changing, I am not talking about the two "test" lines printed out by the loop. These could be replaced by `pass` but I felt `print` would have fewer side effects.

**EDIT 3:** Upon further investigation, this problem runs much deeper than a `for` loop, and thus this question is probably not well-suited for StackOverflow, since the real question seems to be much less focused. Commenting out the line:

```
if flag == 5:
    print "TEST: " + str(key)
```

Also changed program output, as did commenting out just a section of a line, which just appended the literal `+ "Parent: "` to the end of a string that was being printed. Side effects like adding a literal to a string do not seem normal, so I'm going to need to investigate further to figure out why python is behaving so strangely.

Comment: Right..this is gonna be pointless to talk about without code to show.

Comment: Yup. Not much anyone can help you with here, because obviously this is interacting with your code somehow, so we need to see that code in order to determine how it's interacting.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a stale version of some module or other code around?  Try removing the loop from the code, save all files in your editor/IDE and then run them with `python ...` from the command-line.  Then add the loop, save everything, and run again from the command-line.  This avoids using any old modules cached in some interactive session.  And of course you do expect the output to change -- you are adding `print 'test'`, which will print `test`.

Comment: Added source, although I'm still baffled trying to come up with how this could possibly be interacting.

Comment: So how does the output changed? Can you show what it is with and without the loop?

Comment: @RobWatts Added information on how the output changes.

Comment: If you run the code multiple times without changing anything, does the output stay the same?  (Due to hash function randomization, it can change even when not using `random`.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Running code multiple times yields the same result each time. In addition, the differences in output are consistent each time the change is made (i.e. adding the for-loop always causes the same change to occur)

Comment: It's going to be very difficult for anybody to help unless you can give us a minimal reproducible example. Something that doesn't include python modules that we probably don't have, and is as small as you can make the program without having the bug disappear. Is it possible to remove any of your code to shorten it? Even just replacing calls to module functions with mock results and seeing what happens can help you track down the piece of code that is being affected.

Comment: @FunkyDelPueblo I added an answer. Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

No matter what the rest of your code is, that loop will print out "test" twice.
Why? Because for loops don't need a variable, "fff" is just a placeholder to iterate through.
I could have this code:

```
def add(a, b):
    print a + b
add(5, 5)
for fff in range(2):
    print "test"
```

And the output would be:

```
10testtest
```

Comment: I have added a clarification: when I talk above about the output changing, I am not included the two new lines that are printed out--I chose to use `print` as the action in the `for` loop in hopes that it would have fewer side effects than `pass`. I am instead talking about the program's algorithmic output

Comment: Oh, well then that's definitely weird. Maybe it's something to do with extra time for computation?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the bug in your code:

```
alphaset = set() ## 1
...
for i in range(len(partition)):
    for j in range(len(partition[i])):
        alphaset.add(type(partition[i][j])) ## 2
        nodecount += 1
...
count = 0
mapping = dict()
for elem in alphaset: ## 3
    mapping[elem] = count ## 4
    count+=1

alphasize = count
...
for i in range(len(partition)):
    j = len(partition) - i - 1
    ...
    for v in range(len(partition[j])):
        node = partition[j][v]

        SV = list()
        SV.append(mapping[type(node)]) ## 5
```

Here's what happening. At 1, you have a set that is filled at 2 with some types that are taken from a list with a specific "order." Then, at 3 and 4, you iterate over the set and map each element in the `set` to some number. Then, at 5, that number is added to a list. If I understood your code correctly, the rest of the code depends on the "order" of the elements in that list, which depends on the mapping, which in itself depends on the order of the elements in the set at 1.

Now, there are no guarantees of the order of the elements in a `set` nor of the iteration order over it. So, at 3 and 4, and for different runs, you will get different mappings.

The solution is to either explicitly sort the `set` into a `list`, or use an `OrderedSet` which preserves insertion order (assuming the code before point 1 always inserts the nodes in the same order).

Comment: Careful // is not comments in python, its `#`

Comment: Well.. it was intentional so the numbers are not confused with the original comments in the snippet :-).

Comment: copy and paste neanderthals like me got confused.